# discord bot change nicknames if in bad words

Tags: python, discord.py

Hello i have a problem with my discord bot. I want to create event where it change someone nickname if its in bad words and I dont know how to do it.

I have not found anything concrete anywhere on how to do this and I would appreciate it if someone could help get my feet wet on how to do this.

```
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    n = after.nick
    bad_words = ["chuj"]
    if n.lower().count (bad_words) > 0:
        await after.edit(nick="ZMIEN NICK")
```

Comment: Are you able to provide some examples on what you have tried? What is the result of these?

Answer (score 0):

This is not valid Python syntax:

```
if n.lower().count (bad_words) > 0:
```

I'm guessing you mean something like

```
if any(x in n.lower() for x in bad_words):
```

This looks for any of the words in `bad_words` as a substring of `n`. If you mean something else, it should generally not be hard to find an existing question just by articulating a search for the kind of matching you are looking for.